# SFTP - Unable to Overwrite File - "EOF received from remote side"

Tags: windows, java, sftp, file-transfer, sun

I am working with a customer to troubleshoot an error they have when trying to overwrite/"PUT" a file to our SFTP site. When the root directory is empty and they try to upload the file there is no problem but when they try to overwrite an existing file this is when the error occurs. The error they receive when trying a put command in Java Caps is:

> The error is: Batch SFTP eWay error
>   when doing data transfer operation in
>   [PUT()], message=[EOF received from
>   remote side [Unknown cause]].|#]

When they use WinSCP or FileZilla to put the file it overwrites fine with no errors.  We have tried:

- Multiple different files
- Checking their SFTP user permissions
- Gave full access permissions to "everyone" to the user's root directory in Windows
- Recreating their user account
- Ensured no other processes are using/locking the files that are being overwriten

We are using Cerberus Professional FTP server software.  Any ideas of what else we could try?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment in this forum so I'll try an answer:

- Do they use a different username with FTP than with WinSCP/Filezilla?
- Is the target destination directory the same with FTP as with WinSCP/Filezilla?
- For completeness sake, is it the same file being transferred in both circumstances?
- What are the file permissions and owner/group on the target file and its directory?
- Why is this tagged with "java"?
- What version of Solaris is the target machine? (asked due to the "sun" tag)
- Were the tests of WinSCP/Filezilla done from the same client machine as the FTP?
- Does the file have a line terminator at the end, or not?

Sorry to ask so many obvious questions, but since it is not working, all bases need to be covered.

[EDIT]
Responding to your comments, the last answer in comments is "No", that seems to be in answer to "Does the file have a line terminator at the end, or not?"
So, please try adding a "blank line" at the end of the file so that the last character is a line terminator. Reason: it is strange but sometimes I have seem a similar problem with a file that does not have a line terminator at the end.  It is as if the code at the receiving end requires a line terminaotr in order to finish the file.

Comment: Beel, thanks for the response. Answers below.

No, same username
Yes, same directory
Yes, same file
rw-rw-rw
Because my client is using Java Caps to upload the file
The target machine is Windows Server 2008 R2, the source is Sun
Yes, tests of WinSCP/Filezilla performed from same client machine
No

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to format that comment to be easier to read.